# How to Replicate Web Form Call With WinJS.xhr

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-post, winjs

I'm working on a Windows 8 app, building it in HTML5/JavaScript. Part of the functionality in the app requires user authentication. The process in place is via a web form that posts the data back to a server side script and, upon successful authentication, returns a set of cookies. The data in these cookies can then be cached and used to perform several other API calls. I would like to use WinJS.xhr to do this instead of embedding the web page in the app.

First, I assume I can use the `data` parameter of the xhr method to pass the username and password information to the server-side script, but I'm not sure how to format that for a POST.

Second, if I can get the authentication piece to work, is there a way for me to see the cookie content returned in the HTTP response header?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to encode using the FORM encoding standard. I have some [sample code](https://github.com/grork/Utilities/blob/master/js/OAuth.js) that is intertwined in here, but it's very simple to encode it, and set the method to "POST" rather than GET.

For cookie transfer, you should be able to pull those out of the headers and set them as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, Dominic. I was able to structure to post and authenticate using the existing scripts. My only issue now is that I get all the headers back **except** the Set-Cookie items I need. This is apparently standard when using xhr for this type of thing. You don't happen to know how to override that, do you?